# IE7 giving UL a margin even though I told it not to

Tags: css, internet-explorer-7

I have a `ul` which displays fine in normal browsers, and even IE8! However, when I put IE8 into IE7 mode (could that be the issue?), I get the layout to the left (normal behaviour on the right:

[image: IE7 behaviour on the left, normal behaviour on the right.]

And here be my CSS:

```
ul
{
    position: relative;
    z-index: 3;
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    background: transparent;
    margin-left: 0px;
}
```

My question is: How do I get rid of the silly offset (I've used `margin-left -10px` (or another negative value), but of course that affects other browsers too. Thanks for any help :-)

Comment: btw. margin-left: 0px; shouldnt be needed as you set it with margin:0px already

Comment: @BerggreenDK: I did that thinking IE was too stupid to look at the shorthand. Didn't help though. @BalusC: The solution I've come up with actually uses floats now, ironically :-P

Comment: I always build CSS with 4-5 browsers open: Google Chrome, Firefox, Safari and then Internet Explorer (lastest/most common edition) + I have vmWare Workstation/player running with a secondary OS so I can launch eg. Internet Explorer 7 etc. for special testing purpose. My experience is that the less "hack" you use for MSIE, the better the site will work on anything in the future. My own company website has survived 3 versions of Internet Explorer so far without crashing the layout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I normally just use "clean standard CSS" for cross browser compatibility.

Did you test in Google Chrome, Firefox and Safari?

Try setting the "box model" on the UL, by using `display:block;`

Comment: Secondly, if you "clean up" all your HTML tags in the beginning, then you can get ride of weird borders, line-heights etc.

Comment: Thank you! I've changed the CSS to use floats instead of `inline-block` and now it works well.

Comment: `display:inline-block` is simply not supported in IE6/7.

Comment: I know. I was shortening `display: inline-block; zoom: 1; *display: inline`.

Comment: those "tricks/hacks" usually gives me problems sooner or later, I stay more or less away from such. Cant recommend them for anything but quick fixes. No long term solution in my opinion.